# Understanding the logic for finding the count of same-element-pair

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

There's this problem that I was solving and even though I have an O(n) solution but still trying to make sense of the pattern.

The problem being: determine the number of pairs of the same numbers. For e.g for an array `[1,2,3,1,2,1]`. The 4 possible pairs include:

```
[1,1]  // index (0,3)
[1,1]  // index (0,5)
[1,1]  // index (3,5)
[2,2]
```

**The solution:**

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> mp;
int res = 0;
for (auto& elem : nums)
{
   res += mp[elem]++;
}
// res contains the number of possible pairs
```

**Question:**

How does continuously adding the frequency of each element to `res` tell us about the possible pairs between the same numbers?

Is this a valid way of looking at it?

- The first `1` has 0 pairs
- The second `1` has 1 pair
- The third `1` has 2 pairs
- the first `2` has 0 pairs
- The second `2` has 1 pair

---

=> `0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 1 = 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the number of pairs for each number of duplicates is

| number of numbers | number of pairs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 10 |

If we have N identical numbers then the first can pair with the other N-1 values, the second with N-2 because we've counted it's pairing with the first value already and so on. So it's N-1 + (N-2) + ... + 1 and that we know [from Gauss](https://nzmaths.co.nz/gauss-trick-staff-seminar) that comes to N(N-1) / 2

And that's what the map loop does.

The first time we hit an element we add nothing to res but we increment the value in the map for that key by 1. The next time we see that same value the map value is 1 so we add that and increment the map value again. And so on so res goes from

0 -> 1 -> (1 + 2) -> (1 + 2 + 3) -> (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) ...

or

0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 10

which is exactly the same thing i.e. the sum of the numbers up to that point.